# How to validate DataTable with XML Schema?

Tags: xsd

Does anyone know how to validate a DataTable against a particular DataTable XSD (Schema)?
Which would be the best performance-optimized way of doing this?

For example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     attributeFormDefault ="qualified" 
     xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"> ---Content---- </xs:schema>
```

Thanks

Comment: What programming environment? What is a DataTable?